# Using Visual Studio Express 2013 with TFS 2012

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

I have an access to TFS 2012 but I can only use Visual Studio Express for Windows Desktop for the moment. Will I encounter problems besides the limitations of the express edition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VS Express doesn't include a CAL for TFS.  You will have to purchase a CAL separately if you wish to be legal.  But other than that there should be no limitations.